# Самый легкий способ перенести Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Чтобы ничего не слетело. Помню есть плагин хороший. Но забыл название.

Comment: Куда перенести? Опишите поподробнее, что есть желаемый результат.

Comment: Перенести дамп базы и архив движка это слишком сложно?

Comment: @tutankhamun это не сложно, но не правильно :) А как правильно - в ответил Pavel

Comment: @SeVlad Где написано, что это неправильно?

Comment: @tutankhamun В головах тех кто что-то знает про сериализованные массивы и как и какие данные  нужно менять в базе.

Comment: @SeVlad сомнительный источник. Ссылочку бы

Comment: @tutankhamun лучший источник - изучение матчасти. Направление поиска показано. Даже 2 направления. А если хочется поспорить (а не получить знания), тут не место для этого.

Comment: @SeVlad Я не планировал спорить. Я не могу понять, почему такая простая процедура требует плагина. С чего вдруг вы решили что это более правильный путь? Почему затем вы решили, что я не знаю матчасть? Мы имеем: вопрос без конкретики, ответ без аргументов и флуд в комментариях. Вы не согласны?

Comment: @tutankhamun потому что в базе хранятся сериализованные массивы (это различные настройки темы, плагинов, виджетов). Которые нужно исправлять. Простым sql-запросом этого не сделать.
см скрипт для этого: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: @SeVlad Как это соотносится с вопросом топикстартера? Вы хотите меня убедить, что любой установленный на хостинге А вордпресс при переносе на хостинг Б потребует уйму замен в базе?

Comment: @tutankhamun  1 - порой достаточно одной (а не уймы) неправильной записи (точно есть достаточная квалификация что бы это не понимать?), чтобы поломался сайт. 2 - да, любой, **реальный**. чуть более отличающийся, чем из коробки, настроенный. К чему это спор вообще? Я причины объяснил,  неприятие их - не моя забота. Нет достаточно знаний - велком на оф форум, а тут я закругляюсь. И это не говоря уже что, ТС искал плагин, и отметил вопрос решенным.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duplicator - лучший плагин в этом плане

Comment: Пожалуйста, аргументируйте ваш ответ

Comment: При обычном переносе чаще слетают настройки плагинов/темы + по скорости переноса удобнее